# Postgres database last change timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I am writing scripts to backup the content of all my Postgres 9.x and 10.x databases. I need to determine when the last change occurred in a database, or whether the database has changed since the last backup. I would like to know whether a backup is required before I call pg_dump, for example.

Currently I do pg_dump and use md5sum before and after to detect wither something changed. That means I do the pg_dump work anyway, even though it may not have been necessary.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I think SQL Server has a timestamp value that is a incremented globally in a database when something changes. This type of thing could be helpful.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [pg_last_committed_xact()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Do you have to take a logical backup?  If not, then base backups and continuous archiving could save you the effort.

Comment: @dezso: I am stuck with pg_dump at the moment. In the future we may move to continuous archiving.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I will test that and see if it will do the trick.